# Generate combination of days of week in sql(without repetitions)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

If I have a table with the days of the week,like this

[image: Days to Exclude]

I would like that if an 'X' is inserted in one or several days, a table is generated with the different combinations of the days like this

[image: Output]

What algorithm would work for me to generate this combination?.

I try with this but i get repeated combinations.

```
INSERT INTO combinaciones (dia1, dia2, dia3)
SELECT t1.day AS day1, t2.day AS day2, t3.day AS day3
FROM (
SELECT 'Lunes' AS day
UNION SELECT 'Miércoles'
UNION SELECT 'Viernes'
) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT '' AS day
UNION SELECT 'Miércoles' AS day
UNION SELECT 'Viernes' AS day
) AS t2
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT '' AS day
UNION SELECT '' AS day
UNION SELECT 'Viernes' AS day
) AS t3
WHERE t1.day <> t2.day AND t1.day <> t3.day AND t2.day <> t3.day
and t1.day < t2.day AND t2.day < t3.day;;
```

I try with this but appear repeated combinations:

```
 INSERT INTO combinaciones (dia1, dia2, dia3)
 -- Combinaciones de un día
 SELECT day AS dia1, '' AS dia2, '' AS dia3
 FROM (
 SELECT 'Lunes' AS day
 UNION SELECT 'Miércoles'
 UNION SELECT 'Viernes'
 ) AS d1
 UNION
 -- Combinaciones de dos días
 SELECT d1.day AS day1, d2.day AS day2, '' AS day3
 FROM (
 SELECT 'Lunes' AS day
 UNION SELECT 'Miércoles'
 UNION SELECT 'Viernes'
 ) AS d1,
 (
 SELECT 'Lunes' AS day
 UNION SELECT 'Miércoles'
 UNION SELECT 'Viernes'
 ) AS d2
 WHERE d1.day <> d2.day
 UNION
 -- Combinaciones de tres días
 SELECT d1.day AS day1, d2.day AS day2, d3.day AS day3
 FROM (
 SELECT 'Lunes' AS day
 UNION SELECT 'Miércoles'
 UNION SELECT 'Viernes'
 ) AS d1,
 (
 SELECT 'Lunes' AS day
 UNION SELECT 'Miércoles'
 UNION SELECT 'Viernes'
 ) AS d2,
 (
 SELECT 'Lunes' AS day
 UNION SELECT 'Miércoles'
 UNION SELECT 'Viernes'
 ) AS d3
 WHERE d1.day <> d2.day AND d1.day <> d3.day AND d2.day <> d3.day and 
 d1.day < d2.day AND d2.day < d3.day;[![output2][3]][3]
```

Comment: Please learn how to ask question here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I change my question, could you help to appear in the research please @Eric ?

Comment: I think that this question is Clear, could you help you ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with this:

```
INSERT INTO combinations_table (day1, day2, day3)
SELECT d1.day AS day1, d2.day AS day2, d3.day AS day3
FROM (SELECT 'Lunes' AS day
      UNION SELECT 'Martes'
      UNION SELECT 'Miércoles'
      UNION SELECT 'Jueves'
      UNION SELECT 'Viernes'
      UNION SELECT 'Sábado'
      UNION SELECT 'Domingo') AS d1,
     (SELECT 'Lunes' AS day
      UNION SELECT 'Martes'
      UNION SELECT 'Miércoles'
      UNION SELECT 'Jueves'
      UNION SELECT 'Viernes'
      UNION SELECT 'Sábado'
      UNION SELECT 'Domingo') AS d2,
     (SELECT 'Lunes' AS day
      UNION SELECT 'Martes'
      UNION SELECT 'Miércoles'
      UNION SELECT 'Jueves'
      UNION SELECT 'Viernes'
      UNION SELECT 'Sábado'
      UNION SELECT 'Domingo') AS d3
WHERE d1.day <> d2.day AND d1.day <> d3.day AND d2.day <> d3.day;
```

Comment: It´s similar because show repeated combinations... and not consider only Monday or only Wednesday or the combinations Monday-Wednesday or Monday-Friday.